# Send special character to backend

Tags: angular, api, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404, special-characters

I am trying to send special character from Angular front end to my backend api but I am getting 404 Not Found Error.

Say for example... I want to send **test*** but it is giving the error 404.

Can anyone helps how can I send the special character to api?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I understand, are you trying to do parameter binding or something, or trying to have different endpoints? Like instead of your request being domain.blah/end/point?parambinding=* you want domain.blah/end/point* ?

Comment: You need to provide more information than this. You need to provide minimal, complete and verifiable code for anyone to be able to help you. Please refer to this guideline: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand, but I'll try.
If your issue is equal to mine, you can encode base 64 in front end, and decode in backend.